# The way to achieve auto-suggestion

Tags: php, mysql, xml, ajax

I'm looking for the best practise or the most appropriate way to achieve auto-suggestion feature for my website. What I know is, we can do it in many ways like database (currently what I use), plain text file, XML file etc...

In terms of performance and limitations, which way is the most appropriate one? I have many concurrent users.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on your context. Is it an autocomplete out of constants (eg predefined list)? Or is it based on user input?

Comment: How many items in this list ?

Comment: To be honest there may be more than 1000 or maybe 10000, or 10

Comment: If it's that variable, then you should probably go with the database to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a library like [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) or [Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead](https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead) on the client side.

On the server side you create a method to handle your AJAX call and provide a JSON or XML response to the used JS library (whichever you prefer).

However if your values are predefined and the list is small enough, you may but the values already in the javascript as your datasource to avoid requests to the server.

If you are using a database to select your suggestions, you may use something like this:

```
SELECT id, value FROM your_table WHERE value LIKE `%:keyword%`;
```

And replace `:keyword` with the provided user input. I would also add an index on the `value` field to execute this query faster.

Comment: What do you mean by **small enough**? Any limitation?

Comment: I would not include more than 30 in a file. You could maybe go for 50.

Comment: Ordinary "from the beginning" autocomplete only requires a simple index on the column, but if you're autocompleting from anywhere in the text, you'll need a fulltext index; a regular index can't be used in that situation.